# Unable to connect external or internal server required by overtone

Tags: overtone

Overtone is a open source musical programming library written in Clojure which uses the SuperCollider audio engine and synthesis server under the covers.
[i encountered with errors while i tried to connect server. clojure is working fine but i think there may compatibility problem with overtone and also with supercollider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paZNS.png)Need help to sort out this problem.I did refer some answers before mentioned to use  (ns user (:require [overtone.core :refer :all])) instead of (use 'overtone.core),but it didnt work.

Comment: Post all errors here directly as text.

Comment: Here is the complete scenario , im having two folders (1).overtone (2)overtone ;when i try to use external server using (use `overtone.core) it gives me error message-" CompilerException java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: c:\User\Blank\.overtone\log\overtone.log.lck, compiling:(overtone/config/log.clj:23:1)"